# Литература для самостоятельного изучения Си

Tags: c, книги

Хочу изучить Си самостоятельно. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, литературу на эту тему. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: По Си++ эталонный вопрос есть, а по Си вроде не видел...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Книга для начинающих в Си (рассчитана и на начинающих в программировании) - "Изучаем Си", автор Крупник, я по ней изучал. Если Вы ориентируетесь на среду Microsoft Visual Studio, то возьмите книгу Пахомова - "Программирование на C/C++ в Microsoft Visual Studio 2008". Как вариант, можете пройти курсы по языку Си в Интуите: [курс 1](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/43/43/info), [курс 2](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/97/97/info). Вместо второго курса можно взять книгу: "Язык программирования C", авторы: Керникан, Ритчи.

Comment: Спасибо,Керниган,Ритчи у меня уже есть,да и Крупник тоже.Но первые два-больше как справочник,да рассчитана книга на подготовленного пользователя.А Крупник не всё оговаривает.Нужно что-то более полное.Спасибо ещё раз.Ориентируюсь на Linux.

Comment: Linux это правильное решение.

А вот оценка K&R как справочника - это что-то новое.

@rolton, а Вы вообще на чем нибудь программировали?

Comment: Паскаль изучил тоже самостоятельно.

Comment: Если изучили Паскаль и читали, например, Вирта, то IMHO K&R  не должно быть особо сложным (+ практика за клавиатурой с первых шагов).

--

В принципе, Си очень простой язык. Как палка и веревка. И этим-то он и хорош.

Из структур данных только структуры, объединения (пары видов) (аналоги записей и записей с вариантами в паскале) и массивы. 

Типы данных - целые и действительные числа разной длины + машинные адреса (указатели) (в т.ч. на функции).

В основном все. Даже ввода-вывода нет.